SwiftData rollback not updating the UI
I'm building a simple App using SwiftData. In my app a user can create, remove and edit posts. When editing, I want them to be able to hit "Save" to persist the changes or "Cancel" to discard the changes. The approach I'm using is to disable autosave and call modelContext.save() when saving and modelContext.rollback() when discarding the changes. So my modelContainer is defined as follows:
WindowGroup {
     ContentView()
         .modelContainer(for: [Post.self], isAutosaveEnabled: false)
}

and I Save and Cancel like this:
PostForm(post: post)
    .toolbar {
        ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .cancellationAction) {
            Button("Cancel") {
                if modelContext.hasChanges {
                    modelContext.rollback()
                }
                
                dismiss()
            }
        }
        
        ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .confirmationAction) {
            Button("Save") {
                do {
                    if modelContext.hasChanges {
                        try modelContext.save()
                    }
                } catch {
                    fatalError("Failed to save post: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
                
                callback?()
                dismiss()
            }
        }
    }

The issue I am facing is that after calling modelContext.rollback() my Posts aren't updating in the UI, they still show the changes. Restarting the app shows the Posts without the changes so I'm guessing that modelContext.rollback() is in fact discarding the changes and not persisting them in the Storage, the UI is the one that is not reacting to the change. Is this approach correct? How can I make it so that the discarded changes from modelContext.rollback() are updated in the UI?

Could you post a reproducible example?

Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: minimal code.
In particular, show how you pass the post to the view that is use in PostForm(post: post), is it for example, a bindable or just a var?

This is probably a bad idea because you can’t be sure you are only rolling back the change made by this form and not some other thing.

I think when you turn off autosave your need to do the manual save on scene phase change eg when app deactivates or goes fo background

An alternative approach, might be using SwiftData's automatic registration of undo actions for the UndoManager. If you haven't used it, add isUndoEnabled: true  when initializing the model container. Then in your view, @Environment(\.undoManager) var undoManager and call undoManager?.undo() instead of rollback.

UndoManager doesn't work too. Tested.

I found the solution on a related thread: How to make SwiftData @Query updating from changes made on a background context?
Even though I'm not using a background context, this solution works:
extension MyModel: Identifiable {

    var id: String {
        "\(persistentModelID) \(property1) \(property2) ..."
    }

}

For it to work correctly, ensure that the model properties and relationships that are being affected are used in the representation above.
